# Parse string in java with the same start but different ending

Tags: java, parsing, text

I have string like `"abc /123 /456"` and I want to split it into two stings: `"abc 123"` and `"abc 456"`.

I tried:

```
String[] str = MESSAGE.split("/")
```

But didn't provide required result. Could anyone, please, share any ideas with me how to perform it?

Comment: Could you show us a bit more of the code? I want to see how you initialised the `MESSAGE` string

Comment: "But didn't provide required result'.  Please update your question to show what the result was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add a little logic after splitting the `String`.
This is how I would do it:

String s = "abc /123 /456";
    String[] partsOfS = s.split("/");
    String prefix = partsOfS[0];

```
for (int i = 1; i < partsOfS.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(prefix + partsOfS[i]);
}
```

**EDIT**

For the case of the prefix not separated by `/` from the other parts of the `String` but only by space, you will probably need a second split and a second loop, like this:

```
    String s = "abc 123/ 456/";

String[] splitBySpace = s.split(" ");
String prefix = splitBySpace[0];

String[] partsOfS = new String[splitBySpace.length - 1];

for (int i = 1; i < splitBySpace.length; i++) {
    partsOfS[i - 1] = splitBySpace[i].replace("/", "");
}

for (int i = 0; i < partsOfS.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(prefix + " " + partsOfS[i]);
}
```

There may be better solutions concerning performance and programming style, but this is working with your example `String` from the comment.

Comment: but how would you parse string if it would be like String s = "abc 123/ 456/"

Comment: @RatiborShakhov You're welcome... Just accept it and maybe vote it up ;-)

Comment: @RatiborShakhov In that case you would have to split them twice! That is a more complicated task. Maybe I can provide an edit to my question soon.

Comment: @RatiborShakhov See my edit for a possibility of splitting by space first.

Answer (score 2):

Just stick the pieces together in any way you need, like this:

```
String[] str = MESSAGE.split(" /");
String s1 = str[0] + " " + str[1];
String s2 = str[0] + " " + str[2];
```

Also notice that it'd be better to split the string using as pattern `" /"`, that is, with a space before the slash.

Comment: And having this in a method will make it more usable.

Answer (score 1):

you did just fine when deciding to split it , after that you should concat the first element of the splited array with all the other elements to achieve what you want.

here's some code to make it clearer.

```
public class main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       String MESSAGE = "abc /123 /456";
       String[] str = MESSAGE.split("/") ;
       String[] str2 = new String[str.length-1];

       System.out.println(str[0]);

       for ( int i=1 ; i<str.length ; i++) {
           str2[i-1] = str[0]+str[i];
       }

       for ( int i=0 ; i<str2.length ; i++) {
           System.out.println(str2[i]);
       }

   }
}
```